# Assign string distinct values to different variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can i assign distinct values returned by matching row id to variables?

For example in this example, I have 5 columns, and based on the return, the distinct values could return 5 distinct values or 2 or 1, etc. How do I assign each return to a variable?

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var2 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var3 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var4 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var5 varchar(50);

SELECT DISTINCT(names) from Employee WHERE department = 'engineering';

John
Mike
Susan
```

So from above I would have three variables assigned

```
 var1 would be John
 var2 would be Mike
 var3 would be Susan
```

Comment: Loop/cursor with counter - `if counter = 1 set @var1 = xxx. . . . `

Comment: I suspect this is an X-Y problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I don't see a use to putting these values in variables.  You should probably ask a new question and explain what you are really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a sample that is copy-paste ready and annotated each step to try to clarify what I'm doing. This design feels like an anti-pattern to me and there is probably a better way to handle this. Without more context though I'm unable to suggest anything.

This solution uses dynamic SQL, which can be a security risk you should consider before deploying this. The syntax I used is specific to SQL Server, and should work in any version above 2012, and may work on 2008R2.

```
/*Create a temporary table to hold the names for this example. 
References to this table would be replaced by
"SELECT DISTINCT(names) from Employee WHERE department = 'engineering';"
*/
select * 
into #temp 
from (
select 'John' as names
union
select 'Mike'
union 
select 'Susan'
) t;


declare @count int = 0; /* Create a counter variable to hold current position */
declare @total int = (select count(distinct names) from #temp); /* Get the total once */
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '' /* This hold the sql statement we're composing in the While Loop */
declare @name varchar(50); /* Holds the current name to be added to the variable we're generating */

/* 
SQL Server doesn't have a for loop, but it does have a While loop and transactions, indicated by the Begin and End. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql
*/

WHILE @count < @total
BEGIN
set @name = (select names from #temp order by names asc offset @count rows fetch next 1 rows only);
/* Get the next name in the list based on a sorted order,
starting at the offset defined by the current counter and pulling back only the next row.

You may want to store the results of the list of names in it's own variable so that is stable during this loop 
depending on what type of reads you want.
*/
set @sql = concat(@sql,'; declare @var',cast(@count as nvarchar(50)), ' varchar(50) = ''',@name,'''')
/* Get the current value of the SQL Statement we're composing, and append to it. 
The ''' are used to escape adding a ' single quote statement to a string. */
set @count = @count + 1 /* increment the count and begin the loop again if the count is less than the total */
END
/* 
Show the final results for the testing example to make sure it works without having to run a select. You have now have a string that produces 
"; declare @var0 varchar(50) = 'John'; declare @var1 varchar(50) = 'Mike'; declare @var2 varchar(50) = 'Susan'"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql
*/
print @sql
/* 
This pattern is using what is known as Dynamic SQL, and should be carefully evaluated before
being used in production. If your name is ";drop table employees" and you have elevated permissions,
you will have a bad day. See documentation here: https://xkcd.com/327/
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pivot on a row_number, then select into the variables.

For example:

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var2 varchar(50);
DECLARE @var3 varchar(50);

SELECT @var1 = [1], @var2 = [2], @var3 = [3]
FROM
(
  SELECT name, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
  FROM Employee 
  WHERE department = 'engineering'
  GROUP BY name
) src
PIVOT (MAX(name) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3])) pvt;

SELECT 
@var1 as [@var1], 
@var2 as [@var2],
@var3 as [@var3];
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/NEHRK4621)